# My navigation bar 'href' tag is working on Firefox but not on Chrome

Tags: html

my 'href' tag is working on Firefox but not on Chrome. Can you help me check what is the issue?   As I unable to link the pages on other web browser.

```
    <label for="home" class="home"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a></label>
    <label for="tours" class="tours"><a href="tours.html"><i class="fas fa-route"></i>Tours</a></label>
    <label for="destination" class="destination"><a href="destination.html"><i class="fas fa-plane-arrival"></i>Destination</a></label>
    <label for="aboutus" class="aboutus"><a href="aboutus.html"><i class="far fa-address-card"></i>About Us</a></label>
    <label for="contact" class="contact"><a href="contact.html"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i>Contact</a></label>
```

**My issue has been solved with adding <style=“z-index”> within my  tag in html

Comment: Why do you wrap your links in labels? `label`s are for forms and should never contain interactive elements such as anchors or buttons.

Comment: Actually the <label> tag I learn from a website, I see they applied it in their navigation bar so I just followed them. 
By the way, my problem has been solved with adding <style=“z-index:2”>

Comment: So instead of fixing your already invalid HTML, you're just trying a workaround with CSS? It seems you're digging yourself in an even deeper hole.

Comment: No actually the <label> tag is linkable with my css so I should not remove it